# How to combine two pictures in powerpoint permentently?

Tags: image, merge, vsto, powerpoint, office-addins

I am asked to add a button to save a powerpoint file into new in which hidden or unseen objects should either be removed or merged into one object. In details,

The thing should work as follow. If one object is 100% covered overlapped by another object and it is sent to back to be behind the covering object, then I can detect it with two foreach loops and remove it completely. What I cannot do is, if two objects are not covered totally but just have some intersections where some information, which isn't wanted to be delivered all the person the file sent, are stored in that intersection. Therefore, I want to merge those two objects into one to make that information accessible bu others except the creator of the presentation.

I know 2 shapes can be merged but can't make it work for pictures. Of course there may be more than 2 objects to be merged. This is also an issue.

I haven't added any code because I couldn't find any way to try.

Comment: A thought: once you've detected the overlapping shapes, group them, copy them to the clipboard, paste them back as a PNG, move the pasted image to the same coordinates/z-order etc as the original group, then delete the group.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg thanks. That worked. But now I need to distinguish the image shapes specifically gifs from others to make it as an exception. Since I paste the group as png it loses its ability to animate images. How can I detect gif in slide?

Comment: I don't think you can, unless maybe it involves unzipping the PPT and looking within the media folder then figuring out which gifs, if any, correspond to which shapes within what slides. Some later PPT versions may include the name of the picture as Alt text, but all I have in front of me at the moment is pt 2010, and it doesn't do this.

Comment: It is a shame. O have 2013 of it and it does not show any alt text. I can't understand why it does not give that info while it has that info in xml file to relate the info with the shape.

Comment: In many cases, the image stored internally isn't in the same format as the original image file or pasted image, and is always stored internally under a different name than the original image, so I'm guessing that in cases other than GIF, there'd be no value in revealing the image name/type.

Comment: I have tried to unpack the package and read the relations as pp does itself. But while the file is openned, it does not open again. I may need to create a temporary copy of it and read the relation. Does that work? İn the relation part image format is defined such as image/gif even the name of the file is changed.

Comment: You can use SaveCopy to create a temp copy, which would be identical to the original, so that much should work.